# Story about a telepathic wanderer trying to become the "one"

Tags: story-identification

I read a story probably 25 years ago about a lone telepathic wanderer trying to become the "one", or something like that. Throughout the story, he is hiding from some sort of evil pursuers, at least one of whom directs psychic assaults at him. I think he does succeed, and gains complete knowledge of the world, where every rock, tree, person is and what they're doing, etc. I remember it being set in a near medieval setting, yet at one point he encounters an ancient AI computer.

Comment: I believe probably novella length, but I'm simply not sure.

Comment: Absolutely possible...I'm sorry I can't remember much more. My thought is that it was a relatively short novel. It was not online, was definitely hardcopy.

Comment: The Matrix. Definitely The Matrix.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite -  "The Highlander", more likely... and parts 2 and 3 mixed up at that.

Comment: "Medieval setting" plus "ancient AI computer" makes me think it's a post-apocalypse world.

Comment: Unfortunately, definitely not Matrix nor Highlander. Joe L. is correct in that it would seem to be post-apocalypse world in that the computer was, I think, in failing condition due to age, but I don't remember why the computer seemed to help the main character.

Comment: Sounds vaguely akin to some of the books in Octavia Butler's *Patternist/Seed to Harvest* cycle, perhaps "Patternmaster."